# Is it appropriate to edit another user's answer to include important information from their own comments?

Tags: discussion, rejected-edits, edit-summary

A [suggested edit of mine](https://math.stackexchange.com/review/suggested-edits/311838) was recently rejected because

> This edit was intended to address the author of the post and makes no sense as an edit. It should have been written as a comment or an answer.

However, my suggested edit was not intended to address the author. It merely incorporated important information that the author of the [accepted answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1045523/196881) had provided in his own comments. The language is almost entirely his, and the meaning is completely his.

After the answer was posted, the question's author and answer's author went back and forth in its comments. In these comments, the question's author provided important clarification about the question, and the answer's author responded with further answers to address these clarifications. This discussion greatly improved the quality of the question and the accepted answer.

I have already [successfully edited](https://math.stackexchange.com/review/suggested-edits/311776) the question to incorporate its author's clarifying comments. In its current form, the answer by itself no longer satisfies the requirements of the question, and it includes obsolete requests for clarification. The edit I suggested incorporates the answer's author's excellent follow-up information, making the answer stand alone as both correct and complete.

Was this edit appropriate? If so, how should I have ensured that it would be accepted, and is there anything I can do now that it has already been rejected (*e.g.*, resubmit the edit with a revised edit comment)? The comment I originally provided was

> "Including important information found only in comments and removing first sentence (a request for clarification made obsolete by edit to the question)"

If this edit in particular was not appropriate, are actions like these ever appropriate, and under what circumstances? What is the best approach in a situation like this?

Comment: I guess the reviewers did not read the edit summary... Your suggestion was good. I can edit it in myself, but for now I left a comment for the author of the answer, in case he wants to revise the answer himself.

Comment: @Raff, if I resubmit the edit would you be able to approve it? I know it seems silly, but I'd like to be able to get up to 15 rep so that I can ask clarifying questions in the comments. I completely understand the reasons for new user restrictions, and I hope that I'm working within the system to help improve the site's content.

Comment: The Suggested Edit queue moves quickly on Math, and there is no way to tell who will review it now. Probably not me, since I have to go offline for a while now. But you can submit anyway, hopefully the rejection was just an aberration. (BTW commenting requires 50 points... you may have better luck gaining them by asking a good question, or by answering one.)

Comment: The suggested edit was [rejected again](http://math.stackexchange.com/review/suggested-edits/311956), this time because "This edit deviates from the original intent of the post. Even edits that must make drastic changes should strive to preserve the goals of the post's owner." Seems like I should just leave it alone at this point.

Comment: The review queue does not show the comments. This means that I do not know if it was the OP's information or not. As 99% of the time it is the latter I rejected the edit. This edit is indeed valid.

Comment: Yep, glad that all got worked out, and thanks to @Alizter for taking the time to chat with me and push the edit through.

Comment: @Alizter Looks like it would be a good idea to   [Show the post's comments on the “Suggested Edits” review interface](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/150142/).

Comment: @Alizter: The comment in the suggested edit was clear enough. If, as it can happen sometimes, you are unwilling or unable to click on the title to read the comments on the full page, there is a **Skip** button that is made _just_ for this sort of situation.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

According to [this page in the help center](https://meta.stackexchange.com/help/editing), putting information from comments into a post is a good reason to edit. In my opinion, edits like those are great edits.

From that help center page:

> Common reasons for edits include...[t]o include additional information
>   only found in comments, so all of the information relevant to the post
>   is contained in one place

To make sure the edit won't be rejected, it might be a good idea to write something like

> Incorporated important info from comments

in the edit summary.

But....that's how it works on my sites (mostly Mi Yodeya), I don't know how Math works.

You might want to have a chat with the reviewers who rejected your edit in the site's chat room, to see if you can figure out what happened; without reading the question, answer, and comments, I can't know what happened ( *I likely won't; I'm no math person* ).

As a reviewer, if I see that someone left a comment like that, I will click on the "link" link on the side of the page to see who said what comments, to see if the edit was appropriate.

( *One note: make sure that the comments are from the OP; if they're not, then they don't belong in the post. I recall one instance in which I rolled back an edit like that because the info came from comments on a question that didn't belong to the OP.* )

Comment: Thanks for the input. Unfortunately, I'm new to Math.SE (and SE in general), so I don't have enough rep to chat or to comment. Is there any other approach I can take here? Would it be appropriate to re-submit this edit with a revised edit comment like you suggested (I might say "Incorporated important info from _OP's_ comments" to make it clear that it's not from someone else)?

Comment: It shouldn't take too long to get 20 rep ( *though that depends on voting patterns; on MY, one decent first post should get 20 rep [[one user](http://judaism.stackexchange.com/users/6962/adamf) got +13 on his first answer, just today]* ) ....if you get 5 rep (one question upvote, two accepted edits), then you can raise the issue on [Math Meta](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/) if you want.

Comment: Tip for you -- if you want to resubmit the edit, it would probably just be easier to go to the [edit history](http://math.stackexchange.com/review/suggested-edits/311838), copy all the markdown, and then paste that over the current version of the answer.

Answer (score 7):

As [Shokhet mentioned](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/244533/160551), edits like these are [generally encouraged](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/119783/should-i-edit-other-users-posts-to-include-information-from-comments?rq=1).

One thing you may want to do differently is to emphasize you're incorporating comments *from the author of the post* in your edit description.  If you look at the [suggested edit review](https://math.stackexchange.com/review/suggested-edits/311956), the comments aren't really visible in that review queue.

Some reviewers take the time to open up the post and they'll see that you're editing in information the author provided, but as you've found out, others...don't.  Instead, they might think you're adding information provided by *other* people into someone's answer, and edits like that generally are less well received.

To increase your chances of having your edit approved you might try something like:

> Incorporated additional information from the author left in the comments